# How do I Delete data to REST services using AngularJs

Tags: html, angularjs, rest, api

I'm currently trying to use the DELETE function when updating my REST services through Angularjs but I seem to be getting something wrong.

The button isn't working so it won't delete the data i've selected

[image]

The REST services are connected already so they're not the problem, think it's just the code and I can't see the issue. I've tried different methods but none seem to work.

ng-app and controllers are all linked together so no issues there.

The api services are tabled as; 
Id 
RouteStartPoint 
RouteEndPoint

Snippet of html for button to delete item;

```
   <td><button ng-click="removeRoute(route.Id)">Remove Route</button></td>
```

Snippet of js controller file;

```
 $scope.removeRoute = function (route) {
    $http.delete("http://webteach_net.hallam.shu.ac.uk/acesjas/api/route/" + route)
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.init();
        })
        .error(function (error) {


        });

};
```

Comment: Side note: `success` and `error` are deprecated on `$http`, use `then` instead.

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? Error message in the console? Network call is not made? Unexpected server result? Button not working? Computer has a BSoD?

Comment: @Igor sorry let me clarify, button isn't working at all, no errors in console. Other things I don't know unfortunately

Comment: So the issue is `ng-click` is not calling the method `removeRoute`? or is the issue that the `removeRoute` call is erroring? Is that `removeRoute` does not make the http call? Add some breakpoints or use `debugger;` in the code and step through the execution in the browser's debugger.

Comment: I think ng-click isn't calling the function, not sure if I've correctly linked the delete button with the correct ID that I want to remove from the database. Do I need to add breakpoints into the delete function and delete button? Thanks btw